# Undefined property: stdClass::$point

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to display user data in table but when I display point i got the error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$point (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Gelecek_Üyeliği_Sistemi_f\Gelecek_Üyeliği_Sistemi_f\resources\views\backend\usersaction\total.blade.php)

**this is the function i use it to display the data in view**

```php
public function ViewActionUserTotal() {
    $total = DB::table("action_users")
           ->join("users", "users.id", "action_users.user_id")    
           ->select("users.id","users.name","users.email", DB::raw("sum(action_users.point)"))
           ->groupBy("users.id","users.name","users.email",)->get();
    
    return view('backend.usersaction.total',compact('total'));
}
```

**here is the foreach in the table**

```html
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>     
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>User Email</th>
            <th>Total Point</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                   
    @foreach($total as $tot)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$tot->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$tot->email}}</td>
                                
            <td>{{$tot->point}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**when i use dd for the data it show like that**

[image: the data how it is looks like when i send it to the table]

Comment: just make alias for sum query should be like `DB::raw("sum(action_users.point) as point) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to make an alias for sum query .Your query should be like this :

```
$total = DB::table("action_users")
   ->join("users", "users.id", "action_users.user_id")    
   ->select("users.id","users.name","users.email", DB::raw("sum(action_users.point) as point"))
   ->groupBy("users.id","users.name","users.email",)->get();
```

For more :https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries